# iOS Drawing text in the centre of shapes

Tags: ios, core-graphics, core-text, textkit

I'm trying to draw text in the centre of shapes in iOS, an example would be Microsoft Office's insert shape see: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cgqyyuvy6hcv5g8/Screenshot%202014-01-21%2013.48.17.png

I have an array of coordinates that are used to form the shape, which works fine for creating the actual shape.

My first tactic was following this stackoverflow question: [Core Text With Asymmetric Shape on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20476684/core-text-with-asymmetric-shape-on-ios) however I can only get it to draw the text at the bottom of the shape. Is there any way to centre the text vertically and horizontally?

I then had a look at the new TextKit but I got stuck with how to subclass `NSTextContainer` to accept either a `CGPath` or an array of coordinates to create the text container to draw inside.

My backup solution is to use Core Text to draw the text at the centre coordinate of a shape, however this will cause the text to draw outside of the shape on some shapes such as a right angled triangle.

Alternatively, are there any other methods I could use to get some text somewhat in the centre of a shape?

Answer (score 21):

I cherrypicked from these answers and from related questions - none of them were truly satisfying - and came up with this simple solution:

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize.init(width: imageWidth, height: imageHeight))

    let string = "ABC" as NSString

    let attributes = [
            NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(40),
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.redColor()
        ]

    // Get the width and height that the text will occupy.
    let stringSize = string.sizeWithAttributes(attributes)

    // Center a rect inside of the image
    // by going half the difference to the right and down.
    string.drawInRect(
        CGRectMake(
            (imageWidth - stringSize.width) / 2,
            (imageHeight - stringSize.height) / 2,
            stringSize.width,
            stringSize.height
        ),
        withAttributes: attributes
    )

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

The result (nevermind the colours):

[image: String ABC centered in image]

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 3** Version of Luca Davanzo's answer

```
struct UIUtility {

static func imageWithColor(color: UIColor, circular: Bool) -> UIImage? {
    let size: CGFloat = circular ? 100 : 1;
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: size, height: size)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
    if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
        context.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
        if(circular) {
            context.fillEllipse(in: rect)
        }
        else {
            context.fill(rect)
        }
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
    return nil
}

static func drawText(text: NSString, font: UIFont, image: UIImage, point: CGPoint, textColor: UIColor = UIColor.white) -> UIImage? {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size)
    image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height))
    let rect = CGRect(x: point.x, y: point.y, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height)
    text.draw(in: rect.integral, withAttributes: [ NSFontAttributeName: font, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: textColor ])
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage
}

static func circleImageWithText(text: String, font: UIFont, circleColor: UIColor, textColor: UIColor = UIColor.white) -> UIImage? {
    if let image = UIUtility.imageWithColor(color: circleColor, circular: true) {
        let textSize = NSString(string: text).size(attributes: [ NSFontAttributeName: font])
        let centerX = ((image.size.width) / 2.0) - (textSize.width / 2.0)
        let centerY = ((image.size.height) / 2.0) - (textSize.height / 2.0)
        let middlePoint = CGPoint(x: centerX, y: centerY)
        return UIUtility.drawText(text: text as NSString, font: font, image: image, point: middlePoint, textColor: textColor)
    }
    return nil
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

That's a bit tricky. First you have to create a context. (bounds.size is the size of the image)

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bounds.size); 
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
```

Then get the text's bounding box: (font is the font you want to use)

```
CGSize textSize =
[yourText sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font}];
```

draw your text into the context (x and y marks the center of the image)

```
[yourText drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(x, y) withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font}];
```

Get the image

```
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

End image context

```
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

I haven't tested it, but it's the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! - will this work if I'm drawing multiple shapes with text in the middle in drawRect in a single view though?

Comment: Sure ut will. You can handle each drawing separately, if you use cgcontextsavecgstate and cgcontextrestorecgstate

Comment: sorry, I think I am missing something. Why did u get the bounding box in this example?

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 2.0** compatible.

My purpose was draw a circle shape with centered text inside.

```
struct UIUtility {

  static func imageWithColor(color: UIColor, circular : Bool) -> UIImage {
    let size : CGFloat = circular ? 100 : 1;
    let rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, size, size)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor)
    if(circular) {
        CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, rect)
    }
    else {
        CGContextFillRect(context, rect)
    }
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
  }

  static func drawText(text: NSString, font: UIFont, image: UIImage, point: CGPoint, textColor: UIColor = UIColor.whiteColor()) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size)
    image.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height))
    let rect = CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, image.size.width, image.size.height)
    text.drawInRect(CGRectIntegral(rect), withAttributes: [ NSFontAttributeName: font, NSForegroundColorAttributeName : textColor ])
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage
  }

  static func circleImageWithText(text text: String, font: UIFont, circleColor: UIColor, textColor: UIColor = UIColor.whiteColor()) -> UIImage {
    let image = UIUtility.imageWithColor(circleColor, circular: true)
    let textSize = NSString(string: text).sizeWithAttributes([ NSFontAttributeName: font])
    let centerX = (image.size.width / 2.0) - (textSize.width / 2.0)
    let centerY = (image.size.height / 2.0) - (textSize.height / 2.0)
    let middlePoint = CGPointMake(centerX, centerY)
    return UIUtility.drawText(text, font: font, image: image, point: middlePoint)
  }
```

}

With this utility we can easy create an image in this way:

```
let font = UIFont()
let image = UIUtility.circleImageWithText(text: "Center text", font: font, circleColor: UIColor.blackColor())
```